# How to insert data from input fields with same name attribute into different columns in the database

Tags: php

I am trying to insert  two fields from my HTML table which have the same name attribute into two different columns in the database. I am unable to rename the name of each field as the fields are created in a loop. Check it below:

```
foreach ($extrafields->attribute_label as $key => $val){

    $tmpkey='options_'.$key;        
    echo'<td><input name="brice5[]" readonly="readonly" size="20" maxlength="120"  value="'.$extrafields->showOutputField($key, $objp->$tmpkey, '', 1).'"></td>';
}
```

Now this code is taken from dolibarr opensource PHP software. This populates two fields on the table the right way with the right value. Now I have am trying to get data from these two fields on the table and save into another table but am grabbing the data from the table, not from the other DB table. SO now the problem is when I use the below to insert into new table:

```
$mytext = $_POST["mytext"];
$bricei = $_POST["brice5"];

foreach( $mytext as $key => $n ) {
   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT IGNORE into table2(unite,fabrication) VALUES('$bricei[$key]','$bricei[$key]')");
}
```

I get duplicate values on both columns which are what I don't want because it is two different columns on the HTML table so how can I split the data such that even though they have the same name attribute the respective data goes to the respective column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bricei = $_POST["brice5"];
```

contains an array of your fields. Where `$bricei[0]` contains the first column `$bricei[1]` the second etc. So you can manipulate your data with a `foreach` loop

Comment: i had done that by doing this :  $az = $key + 1;  and inserting it as follows:foreach( $mytext as $key => $n ) {
   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into table2(ref,label,desiredstock) VALUES('$bricei[$key]', '$bricei[$az]','$n')");
} but it did not solve the problem

Comment: I just need to know how to get values from two input fields with same name attribute and insert the values to two different columns on the same row in database

Comment: I got the issue fixed by adding an index to the name attribute which autoincrements in the loop thus providing two input fields with distinct name attributes. Once the name attributes are distinct there cannot be duplicate inserts into the database. check my piece of code below  $i = 1; 
            foreach ($extrafields->attribute_label as $key => $val){

  $tmpkey='options_'.$key;  
    

 echo'<td><input name="brice5'.$i.'[]" readonly="readonly" size="20" maxlength="120"  value="'.$extrafields->showOutputField($key, $objp->$tmpkey, '', 1).'"></td>';
  ++$i;

Comment: was right in a way as i needed to make the two input fields have distinct name attributes