# How to prevent duplicate record entry in one row over two columns in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to prevent duplicate entry in the same row over two columns. For example TOM TOM should never occur but TOM PAUL can occur. TOM TOM is in one row but in different columns.

Please help me

Comment: What kind of inputs are you getting? Please show that first. Also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: make the column unique on database

Comment: you add unique previlage on both columns.

Comment: Thanks for replying man maybe you can help me. The whole thing is stemming from this question i asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368996/how-to-insert-data-from-input-fields-with-same-name-attribute-into-different-col/38369171#38369171     I am trying to get post data from two fields from my table with the same name attribute so on inserting into db to two different columns the same value gets entered into the two different columns in the database on the same row. I want it to enter only one value per column on the same row though it is the same array.

Comment: I think there's no simple way to do this at the data base level.

Comment: what i have tried so far : 
$bricei = $_POST["brice5"];
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["brice5"]);$i++)

{
    //set the value for variable
    $vari=$_POST['brice5'][$i];
    $test=$_POST['brice5'][$i];
    
   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT DISTINCT into table2(unite,fabrication) VALUES('$vari','$test')");
}

Comment: @Strawberry before insert trigger and raise a user defined error if the condition is met. But I would argue that this check should rather be in the application logic, not in the database layer - unless you have multiple different applications connecting to the same database that have the same requirement.

Comment: @shadowPlease can you write out the logic in php here for me to see i dont know how to do it

Comment: @Landry are you unfamiliar with the == comparison operator in php? Seriously?

Comment: @shadow  can you just please help me out with this if you can.

Comment: Make a decent attempt at it and we can help you to fix it.

Comment: I got the issue fixed. I was using the same name attribute for two input fields so what i did was to use an increment $i on the input name like this $i = 1; 
            foreach ($extrafields->attribute_label as $key => $val){

  $tmpkey='options_'.$key;  
    

 echo'<td><input name="brice5'.$i.'[]" readonly="readonly" size="20" maxlength="120"  value="'.$extrafields->showOutputField($key, $objp->$tmpkey, '', 1).'"></td>';
  ++$i;  and it did the trick no more duplicate